# Move Cursor to next text Field pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple text fields in my form and I want when user enters data in one text field and press enter that the cursor moves to another text-field which is next to current text field. I visited some question but didn't find them useful.

```
$("#username").keypress(function (event) {
    alert("inside function");
    if(event.keyCode == 13) { 
        textboxes = $("input.username");
        debugger;
        currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this);
        if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
            nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1];
            nextBox.focus();
            nextBox.select();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false; 
        }
    }
});
```

this is my code which i have tried 
an other thing that when the data entered in last text field then the form will submit on mouse click on the button not with enter press.

Comment: @Teemu not working i tired :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".username").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        textboxes = $("input.username");
        currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this);
        if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
            nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1];
            nextBox.focus();
            nextBox.select();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

<kbd>ENTER</kbd> doesn't trigger `keypress` in all browsers, used `keyup` instead. Also attached eventlistener to each `input` instead of a wrapper.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9T9e/).

Your code with event delegation will also work with a slight change:

```
currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(event.target);
```

`this` on above sentence would refer to the wrapper instead of the `input`, `event.target` refers to the actual element which fired the event.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9T9e/1/).

Comment: your js code and fiddle is working but i also want that my form will not submit on pressing enter key beacue when i press on enter key to move to next textfield my form will submit how i will prevent this

Comment: Return `false` from the keyup handler in any case of ENTER. Please see the edit.

Comment: I just tried this in Firefox 44.0 on Linux, and found that form submission there is triggered on keydown, which means the submission event fires before the keyup event advancing focus to the next field has a chance to fire. Changing keyup to keydown fixed the problem. Haven't done any other cross-browser testing yet.

Comment: The docs for [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) says, "Cancelable: no" and "Default action: none". [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)  has these properties. So, looks like I've chosen an incorrect event for this, `keydown` is the one to use currently. The linked fiddle works though, (also with a form) in FF43 + Win7.

Comment: event.target works but textboxes.index(this) doesn't work

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi No? The fiddle still works for me. Notice, that the snippet uses jQuery 1.11.0 from year 2014 and there's no delegation. In the delegation case you need `textboxes.index(event.target)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this , as soon as you press it will move to next input field in the form, and when it reaches submit button it will submit the form

```
            <html>
     <head>
       <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myForm input').keydown(function(e){
             if(e.keyCode==13){       

                if($(':input:eq(' + ($(':input').index(this) + 1) + ')').attr('type')=='submit'){// check for submit button and submit form on enter press
                 return true;
                }

                $(':input:eq(' + ($(':input').index(this) + 1) + ')').focus();

               return false;
             }

            });
        });
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <form action="" id="myForm"  >
        <input type='text'  name='firstField'>
            <input type='text' name='secondField'>

            <input type='text' name='secondField'>

            <input type='text' name='secondField'>
        <input type='submit'>
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var index = $("input[type='text']").index(this);
    $("input[type='text']").eq(index + 1).focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

**It worked perfectly for me and supports almost every jquery versions!**

Comment: Short and simple without any tension about current textbox, after textbox and ao on...

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $('input:text:first').focus();

    $('#txtLoginID').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if ($('#txtLoginID').val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtPassword').focus();

            }
        }
    });


    $('#txtPassword').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtFirstName').focus();

            }
        }
    });

    $('#txtFirstName').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if ($('#txtFirstName').val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtLastName').focus();

            }
        }
    });

    $('#txtLastName').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if ($('#txtLastName').val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtPhoneNo').focus();

            }
        }
    });


    $('#txtPhoneNo').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if ($('#txtPhoneNo').val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtEmailID').focus();

            }
        }
    });

    $('#txtEmailID').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if ($('#txtEmailID').val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtAddress').focus();

            }
        }
    });

    $('#txtAddress').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if ($('#txtAddress').val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#btnSignUp').focus();

            }
        }
    });

you can do for text ,password,textarea its a long process but no confusion
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  **This code was perfectly worked in  cursor move to next contenteditable td and textboxes and dropdown list within td ,and datepicker within textbox by reference in class strong text**

    `var $input = $('.EnterlikeTab');
        $input.bind('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var nxtIdex = $input.index(this) + 1;
                $(".EnterlikeTab:eq(" + nxtIdex + ")").focus();
            }
        });`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>On Enter Button Click, focus next Input Field</h2>
    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" name="f">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="name ">Name:</label> <input type="text "
                class="form-control register_form" name="name"
                placeholder="Enter Name ">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="phone ">Phone:</label> <input type="text "
                class="form-control register_form" name="phone"
                placeholder="Enter Phone ">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="email ">Email:</label> <input type="email "
                class="form-control register_form " name="email"
                placeholder="Enter email ">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="pwd ">Password:</label> <input type="password "
                class="form-control register_form " name="pwd"
                placeholder="Enter password ">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit " value="submit"
                class="btn btn-default form-control register_form ">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>



<script>
    var allFields = document.querySelectorAll(".register_form");
    console.log(allFields)

    let count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        allFields[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                console.log('Enter clicked')

                console.log(count)
                // event.preventDefault();
                var n = f.name.value;

                var n1 = m12(count);
                if (this.parentElement.nextElementSibling
                        .querySelector('input')
                        && n1) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector(
                            'input').focus();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    function m12(m4) {
        console.log(m4 + "baluu")
        console.log(m4 + 1)
        var n79 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[m4].value;
        console.log(n79 + "annnnana")
        var n = f.name.value;
        var m5 = f.phone.value;
        var m6 = f.email.value;
        var m7 = f.pwd.value;

        if (m4 == 0) {
            if (!(/^[a-z]{6}$/.test(n79))) {
                alert("name should contaon 6 letter")
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }

        } else if (m4 == 1) {
            if (!(/^[0-9]{6}$/.test(n79))) {
                alert("email should contaon 6 letter")
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }

        } else if (m4 == 2) {

            if (m6.length == 0) {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }

        } else if (m4 == 3) {
            if (m7.length == 0) {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }

        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.