# can't focus next input field using ascii 46 `.` (period)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 4 text boxes for IPv4 addy entry that I want to have focus move to the next text field when the user presses the period ascii # 46.

The following JS/jQ (which I basically lifted from: [Move Cursor to next text Field pressing Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853696/move-cursor-to-next-text-field-pressing-enter)) works for ascii codes for enter (13), esc, and even the space char (32):

```
<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    function ipfNext() {
      //alert( 'FUNC ipfNext' );
      $( document ).ready( function()  {
        $( '#formContent .inputTextIpf').keydown( function( e )  {
          if( e.keyCode == 46 ) {
            $( ':input:eq(' + ( $( ':input' ).index( this ) + 1 ) + ')' ).focus();
            return false;
          } // close IF 
        }); // close FUNC e
      }); // close docReady FUNC
    } // close FUNF ipfNext
  </script>
```

but it doesn't seem to fire for regular printing ascii codes like 46 `.`. How can the code be modified to allow regular ascii printing chars to initiate the field tab when pressed?

**HTML input field that fires fine with ascii control chars but not printing chars**

```
<input type="text" id="ipf1" name="ipf1" class="inputTextIpf" maxlength="3" onkeyup="return ipfNext();" value=
        <?php
        if ( !empty( $_SESSION[ 'ipf1' ] ) ) {
          echo '"' . $_SESSION[ 'ipf1' ] . '"> . ';
        } else {
          echo '""> . ';
        } // close IF
      ?>
```

Comment: add the HTML too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes, the keycode for period `.` is 190 and not 46. The keycode for 46 refers to the DEL key according to the same page.

Comment: Weird, but that's the fix alright. Other pages like: http://www.asciitable.com/ define 46 as the period key and 127 as the DEL key. But now `if( e.keyCode == 13  || e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 190 ) {` works as expected, so that when either the space, enter or period keys are entered in the IP ADDY fields the cursor tabs over.