# How to move cursor to the next text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my work-through I tried to implement moving focus from one text field to another by pressing enter. I have found possible answers in the following links:

[How to go to next textbox when enter is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511535/how-to-go-to-next-textbox-when-enter-is-pressed)
[Move Cursor to next text Field pressing Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853696/move-cursor-to-next-text-field-pressing-enter)

But none of these are working for me. My code:

```
<script>
$('input[type='text']').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
</script>
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
```

Comment: About your actual question - it has nothing to do with the server side. What you do is completely client-side and is fixed by moving the script tag below the inputs.

Comment: Why would you use enter? Literally no one expects that behavior.

Comment: @Waxi you're right. Using Enter to get to the next input would be useless since no one would make use of it. The default key for switching input focus is the **Tab key** which works without javascript

Comment: @Al.G. : I have updated the code according to your suggestion. But it's not still working.

Comment: @DragonBall did you solve your problem using either my or someone else's answer? You did not respond to my last comment.

Comment: @Al.G. I haven't solve the problem. I was out of my home. Just reached.  Still I don't get any solution. Can you please help me further.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
 })

 $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(event) {
     if(event.keyCode === 13) {
         $(this).next().focus();
     }
 });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script>
<form>
     <input type="text"/>
     <input type="text"/>
     <input type="text"/>
     <input type="text"/>
     <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Because jQuery isn't included. The code itself looks fine.

Comment: FIXED! Thanks for pointing that one out - can someone give me hand, how to include jquery in the snippets? Here's a fiddle for now: https://jsfiddle.net/qbbcmrnk/

Answer (score 1):

Just update `$('input[type='text']')` to `$('input[type="text"]')`. You had unclosed strings.

Working codepen [here](http://codepen.io/nicolae-olariu/pen/JWzbBr).

Comment: Actually I am writing the code inside a variable $var in php. then echo $var. That's why I used $('input[type='text']'). otherwise it shows error, 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/1.php on line 4**

Comment: @DragonBall but after you removed the php part, the solution of Nicolae should work?

Comment: @Al.G. and also this one isn't working, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJMpEj

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening:

```
<!-- Start loading the page -->
<script>
// execute javascript. Note that there
// are no inputs on the page currently - they will be loaded later

// This selector matches nothing:
$("input[type='text']").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
</script>
<!-- JavaScript executed. Now add inputs to the page -->
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
```

What you can do is either move the `<script>` below the inputs (easiest) or move the `keyup` listener to a onload function:

```
$(function(){
// i.e. wrap your js here

// the js here will be executed only after page has loaded
});
```

Comment: @DragonBall sorry, I've forgotten to fix the quotes. Now should work.

Comment: @AI.G. I am now adding an image. It's not working, https://postimg.org/image/ozvdutibz/